# Not looping correctly

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli

So im accessing the database to retrieve a list of employee ids and then take that array of employee id to run a query against another table on the database that gets all the information of the person based off the employee id but I'm only getting the last value in the statement but I need to get and loop for all of them. Can anyone see my error?

```
public function manager_list()
{
    $results = array();
    $managers = $this->db->query('select `employee_id` from `managers`');

    foreach($managers->result() as $row)
    {
        $employee_id = $row->employee_id;
    }

        $query = $this->db->query('select `employee_id`, `ssn`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `department`, `title`, `status` from `employees` where `employee_id` = "'.$employee_id.'"');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $results[] = array(
            'employee_id' => $row->employee_id,
            'ssn' => $row->ssn,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'last_name' =>$row->last_name,
            'department' =>$row->department,
            'title' =>$row->title,
            'status' =>$row->status,
        );
        }
    return $results; 
}
```

This is using the code igniter framework.

Comment: You need to  move the closing brace after getting the employee ID to right above the return. The second query (and loop) needs to be within the braces for the first loop.

Comment: 1. The closing `}` of the `for`-loop is misplaced. 2. Surely this could be done better with a single SQL query using a JOIN rather than a whole bunch of queries in a loop.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean @MarkS.

Comment: Why not do a JOIN in the query? Do you have a need to run two queries?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes I need to run two quires but that results of the first query is going to affect the results of the second query.

Comment: There is really no need for two queries here unless you're using the employee_id's somewhere else that you've not told us about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You could shorten this even more if you did it in a single query, but since you say you must have two, here is a short version of your second query, with no need for the foreach loop:</strike>

```
$query = $this->db->query('
select `employee_id`, `ssn`, `first_name`, 
       `last_name`, `department`, `title`, `status` 
from `employees` where `employee_id` = "'.$employee_id.'"');

return $query->result_array();
```

Using Active Records:

```
return $this->db
->select('`employee_id`, `ssn`, `first_name`, 
       `last_name`, `department`, `title`, `status`')
->where(array('employee_id' => $employee_id))
->get('employees')
->result_array();
```

---

UPDATE

Here is a short version with JOIN (replaces your whole code):

```
public function manager_list()
{
    return $this->db
    ->select('e.employee_id, e.ssn, e.first_name, 
              e.last_name, e.department, e.title, e.status')
    ->join('managers AS m', 'e.employee_id = m.employee_id')
    ->where(array('e.employee_id' => $employee_id))
    ->get('employees AS e')
    ->result_array();
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with a join?

Comment: Yes, but you said in the comments you want two queries... Do you want a join version?

Comment: id like too see a join, it technically doesn't have to be two

Comment: Alright then, using JOINS seems natural in this case. I thought you had some specific reason not to do it.

Comment: Thank you! saved me a headache. The only reason I asked not to use one was because I was unfamiliar with the join clause but it served to be very useful.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, this was pretty much the primary usage of joins - a textbook example. They are a very powerful tool and I'd strongly suggest you learn about all of them (left, right, inner, outer...).

Answer (score 1):

Do one query with a JOIN and do one loop -

```
public function manager_list()
{
    $results = array();
    $managers = $this->db->query('SELECT `m`.`employee_id`, `e`.`ssn`, `e`.`first_name`, `e`.`last_name`, `e`.`department`, `e`.`title`, `e`.`status` FROM `managers` AS `m` JOIN `employees` AS `e` ON `m`.`employee_id` = `e`.`employee_id`');

    foreach ($managers->result() as $row){
        $results[] = array(
            'employee_id' => $row->employee_id,
            'ssn' => $row->ssn,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'last_name' =>$row->last_name,
            'department' =>$row->department,
            'title' =>$row->title,
            'status' =>$row->status,
        );
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I believe the whole foreach part is slightly redundant because it does exactly what the native CI method `result_array()` does, right?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant. I was just making enough change in the OP's code for the point to be made about the JOIN. BTW +1 for your excellent elegant solution @Shomz

Comment: Sure, sure, just checking because I wrote my answer from the top of my head, without testing. :) Thank you, your solution is good, too! +1

Comment: Thank you @Shomz and Jay for telling me the foreach is redundant. I was unaware it was because the first time I looked up how to return an array with code igniter was with a foreach. You have saved me some time, and code.